# How would it be possible to add a caption to the bottom of a table?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, caption

I have a table which has a caption which appears on top of the table.

I'd need another caption to appear at the bottom of the table. how would  it be possible?

```
<table>
    <caption>My Table - Start</caption>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfooter></tfooter>
    <caption>My Table - End</caption>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mock one by doing the following, and applying some CSS

```
<table>
  <caption class="cap">some caption text</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="cap foot">
        This is pretty much a footer caption.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Here's an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pVCsg/1/)

Comment: this was quite interesting; thanks :) - did you write that example yourself?

Answer (score 6):

You should put the <caption> at the top of the table, right below the <table> tag.  Then you can use the CSS:

caption {
    caption-side: bottom;
}

to get it below the table. And only one caption per table as a previous person wrote. If you need a table title, then either use <th> or put a heading outside the table and use CSS to position it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only have 1 caption per table and it must appear after the table tag.
You could add a div right after the table and put your caption there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread but I haven't seen a good answer considering bottom captions are easily supported via this CSS...

```
caption {caption-side:bottom;}
```